# How to get maya main window pointer using PySide?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, maya

I've used PyQt4 in maya quite a bit, and generally I've found it quite easy to switch to PySide, but I'm having trouble getting the pointer to the main window. Perhaps someone can understand what's going wrong.

Here's what I do in PyQt4:

```
import sip, PyQt4.QtCore
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui
ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
parent = sip.wrapinstance(long(ptr), PyQt4.QtCore.QObject)
```

This works fine. When I try the same in PySide:

```
import sip, PySide.QtCore
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui
ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
parent = sip.wrapinstance(long(ptr), PySide.QtCore.QObject)
```

I get the following error:

```
# Error: wrapinstance() argument 2 must be sip.wrappertype, not Shiboken.ObjectType
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 4, in <module>
# TypeError: wrapinstance() argument 2 must be sip.wrappertype, not Shiboken.ObjectType #
```

Anyone know what's going wrong?

Answer (score 15):

You need to import `shiboken` instead of `sip` and pass `QWidget` to `wrapInstance` instead of QObject

**Edit:** Maya2017 contains `shiboken2` and `PySide2` instead of `shiboken` and `PySide` as pointed out in comments below.

```
import shiboken
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import maya.OpenMayaUI as apiUI

def getMayaWindow():
    """
    Get the main Maya window as a QtGui.QMainWindow instance
    @return: QtGui.QMainWindow instance of the top level Maya windows
    """
    ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if ptr is not None:
        return shiboken.wrapInstance(long(ptr), QtGui.QWidget)
```

Please note that `sip` has `wrapinstance` in which *i* is not capital but in `shiboken.wrapInstance` *i* is capital.

`shiboken.wrapInstance()` requires wrapertype as a second argument, so you can pass `QWidget` as a second argument.

Comment: shiboken is not available on Maya 2017.  People use this to get the main window link now: for obj in QtWidgets.qApp.topLevelWidgets()... then check if any has objectName() == 'MayaWindow'  . Don't forget that PySide is now PySide2

Comment: shiboken is now shiboken2. Right now, shiboken2 is not documented on Maya2017 official docs.

Answer (score 4):

Because the previous answer has become somewhat out-of-date, here is a more current version to save someone the trouble of having to update it themselves.

Two approaches for getting the maya main window:

- using PySide2:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

global app
app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() #get the qApp instance if it exists.
if not app:
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)


def getMayaMainWindow():
    mayaWin = next(w for w in app.topLevelWidgets() if w.objectName()=='MayaWindow')

    return mayaWin

print(getMayaMainWindow())
```

- Using shiboken2 and the maya api:

```
import maya.OpenMayaUI as apiUI
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

try:
    import shiboken2
except:
    from PySide2 import shiboken2


def getMayaMainWindow():
    ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    mayaWin = shiboken2.wrapInstance(long(ptr), QtWidgets.QWidget)

    return mayaWin

print(getMayaMainWindow())
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on your needs, the following more modern code might be easier too use.
since maya now has a build in method to access the main window in qt

```py
import pymel.core as pm
mayaWindow = pm.ui.Window("MayaWindow").asQtObject()
your_widget.setParent(mayaWindow)
```